# How to give parameter to Trigger function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `needitems` as follow:

```
itemid   qty 
  5       10
  3       20
```

I wrote a trigger that on insert/update/delete it will copy the **new** record and save it in a table log : `neededitems_log`.

The thing is that I also need to know the productid. That information is avliable in the functions that did the insert/update/delete... however in the trigger I have no access to it.  How can the function that did the insert/update/delete pass a variable to the trigger? 
if it can't be done what I can do?

with the above example...

assume that function X did update on itemid from qty 10 to qty 15 of productid 5555... I want the 
neededitems_log to show:

```
itemid   qty productid
  5       15   5555
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot to pass  parameters to triggers dynamically. It isn't possible with any clean mechanisms. There is few ugly methods - session variables and others, but I cannot to advice it. When you are feeling the necessity of additional parameters for triggers, then your design is wrong. So **don't do it**.

The triggers are nice when they are light - the triggers should be used primary for checking and for auditing. When you needs more complex work, then you should to use classic functions. The parametrization of functions is much stronger, and the maintainability is much better. Too complex triggers is bit trap and usually big fail.

If you really need it - then the session variables are the less wrong than other ugly solutions:

```
postgres=# do $$
begin
  perform set_config('custom.var1', 10::text, true);
  raise notice 'session variable var1 = %', current_setting('custom.var1');
end;
$$;
NOTICE:  00000: session variable var1 = 1
DO
```